# Why does FileZilla start its own ssh-agent process?

Tags: macos, ssh, ssh-keys, sockets, ssh-agent

Why does FileZilla start its own ssh-agent process? When I open my terminal, an ssh-agent gets created with socket location `/var/folders/sm/4bt9kz951dg4s5kq1jwy57tc0000gn/T//ssh-nWola5Puaw6o/agent.2855`.

And when I try to connect to a server using FileZilla, it starts another ssh-agent instance at `/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.YiC62e7kHT/Listeners`.

Is this normal? It seems that FileZilla cannot read the SSH keys loaded in ssh-agent because it uses its own ssh-agent socket.

This issue happens on macOS Sonoma 14.2.1 using the latest FileZilla version, Zsg, OhMyZsh and PowerLevel10k.

Here is a screenshot of example processes:

[image]

The user starting them is my own user account.

Here is another screenshot of the permission of both socket files:

[image]

Comment: Please [do not cross-post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64069/355310). For the record, the other copy is [on Unix & Linux SE](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/767914/108618)

Comment: Did you start FileZilla from Terminal? It cannot know about an existing agent if it doesn't inherit its environment variables.

Comment: @DanielB No, I did not. I did not know it was necessary, and I don't know why it worked the first time I opened FileZilla after installing it.